# How to let developer get a look on pull-requests

Tags: git, github

I have a question.

I created a pull-request on Github repository whose last activity is half a year ago. But I am not sure whether this patch would be reviewed by developer. I do want this patch be applied to the repository.

I thought some way to notify the patch to the developer, but I am wandering whether these are effective way.

1. tweet
2. Github comment
3. mail

Could you tell me the effective way to notify patch to developer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the interaction between developers, and not about coding per se. It *might* be on topic on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/, but that's for the community of there to decide.

Comment: I was wandering whether this topic should be on-topic. Thank you for your comment. I'll post this question on opensource.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no special way to signal to the developer about the pull request. Github sends notifications about pull requests automatically, bit they can be turned off, of course.

If the developer is ignoring you and you really need that fix, the best way is to clone the repo and have your own version of the code, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the pull request u can assign this PR to the person u want to notify or get it reviewed by . You can find the assignee button in the bottom right of the PR page . You can assign multiple persons as well.